# Publish WSUS Package with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-delivery

i would like to publish the result of a build via WSUS.
My build creates an InnoSetup.
I have successfully tested to publish the setup with [WSUS Package Publisher](https://wsuspackagepublisher.codeplex.com/documentation) 
But i would like to automate this last step. I was not able to automate Package Publisher or [Local Update Publisher](http://www.localupdatepublisher.com/) and i could not find a tool that can be automated. Did i miss something?

For example: I need a tool that I can launch via commandline, that takes parameters or a config file and creates and publishes the setuppackage.

Do i have to package each new version manually?

Thank You
Michael Grünwaldt